# How to create click event for dynamically created user controls in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, events, user-controls, universal

I'm creating a Windows Universal App which contains a ListView filled with User-Controls. User-Controls are added to ListView dynamically during runtime, based on the elements from the database.

```
public void ShowFavorites()
    {
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), (Application.Current as App).DBPath))
        {
            var Favorites = conn.Table<Favorites>();

            lvFavorites.Items.Clear();

            foreach (var fav in Favorites)
            {
                FavoriteItem favItem = new FavoriteItem();
                favItem.Favorite = fav;
                lvFavorites.Items.Add(favItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

So how can i create an event that that triggers when the user-control is pressed?

Comment: Are you using a DataTemplate?

Comment: No, i'm not using DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the control, all you need to do is simply link the control to a new event:

```
// Dynamically set the properties of the control
btn.Location = new Point((lbl.Width + cmb.Width + 17), 5);
btn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 23);
btn.Text = "Add to Table";

// Create the control
this.Controls.Add(btn);

// Link it to an Event
btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
```

Then, when you (in this case) click on the newly added button, it will call your `btn_Click` method:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working even for items with diffrent text etc.
I gonna explain it based on a button beeing added to a panel.
You need to have a List<> in which you store the items, in this case buttons.

```
List<Button> BtList = new List<Button>();
```

and I also have a Panel in this case.

```
Panel PanelForButtons = new Panel();
```

Here is my code I hope it helps you:

```
    void AddItemToPanel()
    {
        //Creating a new temporary item.
        Button TempBt = new Button();
        TempBt.Text = "Hello world!";

        //Adding the button to our itemlist.
        BtList.Add(TempBt);

        //Adding the event to our button.
        //Because the added item is always the last we use:
        PanelForButtons.Controls.Add(BtList.Last());
        BtList.Last().Click += MyButtonClicked;
    }
```

And here is the event:

```
    void MyButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //First we need to convert our object to a button.
        Button ClickedButton = sender as Button;

        //And there we have our item.
        //We can change the text for example:
        ClickedButton.Text = "The world says: \"Hello!\"";
    }
```